# How to import local fonts into a Gatsby website?

Tags: css, gatsby, webfonts

To begin, I know that's probably a silly one. Fonts always give me trouble, somehow such a common thing is really not easy to find information on. All tutorials online make it look extremely easy (including Gatsby's own), no one really covers potential issues.

I'm using [this guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/using-local-fonts/), it's simple, but it gives an idea: declare @font-face in a separate CSS file, import that file in your app. So here's my structure:

```
src/
┣ assets/
┃ ┗ fonts/
┃   ┣ DMSerifDisplay-Italic.ttf
┃   ┣ DMSerifDisplay-Regular.ttf
┃   ┗ fonts.css
┣ components/
┃ ┣ ...
┃ ┗ layout.tsx
┗ pages/
  ┣ 404.tsx
  ┗ index.tsx
```

Both fonts are imported in fonts.css like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DM Serif Display';
  src: url('./DMSerifDisplay-Regular.ttf') format('ttf');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DM Serif Display';
  font-style: italic;
  src: url('./DMSerifDisplay-Italic.ttf') format('ttf');
}
```

Then that file is imported in layout.tsx (which is the basis of any page):

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'
import { Header } from './header'
import { Footer } from './footer'
import { GlobalStyles } from './global-styles'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'
import { theme } from './sc-theme'
import '../assets/fonts/fonts.css'
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

export const Layout: FC = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <Header />
      <main>{children}</main>
      <Footer />
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

However, I don't see the fonts be imported in the network tab. I tried adding some styles into fonts.css and they do indeed load, so the file is there in the bundle, but not the fonts. Let me know if any other information would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try that?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DM Serif Display';
  src: local('DM Serif Display'), url('./DMSerifDisplay-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'DM Serif Display';
  font-style: italic;
  src: local('DM Serif Display'), url('./DMSerifDisplay-Italic.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: That worked! I tried a couple of variations and it was about the format. What would `local` function do? Prefer local font, if installed?

Comment: if you have local files that describe your font family then it does not execute `url` function

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with local fonts as well. Finally I've ended up with [Typography](https://kyleamathews.github.io/typography.js/) and [Fontsource](https://github.com/fontsource/fontsource) projects:

```
npm i \
    typography \
    typography-theme-funston \
    gatsby-plugin-typography \
    react-typography \
    @fontsource/cabin-condensed \
    @fontsource/patua-one
```

You can choose to use both projects or any of them independently at your own convenience.

#### Typography

**./gatsby-config.js**

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-plugin-typography",
  options: {
    pathToConfigModule: "./src/utils/typography",
    omitGoogleFont: true, // using local fontsource fonts instead
  },
},
```

**./src/utils/typography.js**

```
import Typography from "typography"
import funstonTheme from "typography-theme-funston"

const typography = new Typography(funstonTheme)

export default typography
```

#### Fontsource

**./gatsby-browser.js**

```
import "./src/css/index.css"
```

**./src/css/index.css**

```
@import "~@fontsource/cabin-condensed/latin-400.css";
@import "~@fontsource/cabin-condensed/latin-700.css";
@import "~@fontsource/patua-one/latin-400.css";

... // other styles you need, e.g. https://fonts.google.com/icons
@import "~@fontsource/material-icons/base-400.css";
```

This works like a charm! Everything is loaded from your domain.

#### Embed base64 encoded fonts in CSS

One more snippet, if you wish to embed Base64-encoded fonts into your css as a data link (`url(data:font/woff;base64,...`). URL-loader supports `limit` option, but configuring it is a bit tricky.

**./gatsby-node.js**

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, getConfig, actions }) => {
  if (stage !== "build-javascript" || process.env.gatsby_executing_command !== "build") {
    return
  }
  const config = getConfig()
  const fontsRegex = /\.(eot|otf|ttf|woff(2)?)(\?.*)?$/
  const fontsLoader = config.module.rules.find((rule) => rule.test && String(rule.test) === String(fontsRegex))
  ;[].concat(fontsLoader.use).forEach((it) => {
    it.options = it.options || {}
    it.options.limit = 100_000 // Embed all Fonts into CSS to reduce outbound connections
  })
  actions.replaceWebpackConfig(config)
}
```

Comment: This will massively increase your FCP, so be careful with adding base64 fonts to CSS as it will increase the HTML file size drastically.

Comment: It's hard to tell about 'massively' without measurements for the particular project and usage scenarios. In my case this change reduced loading time x2 times for mobile users.

Comment: We ran about 20 tests on webpagetest.org, focusing on a slow 3G network. Adding fonts as Base64 increased the HTML size from 30KB to nearly 200KB, hitting our FCP hard - it jumped from 1.9 seconds to 5 seconds. Just sharing our experience; perhaps it's font size and different weight variations, but that's what we encountered. In our case the best results we had is when we preloaded the fonts as woff2. Keeping the HTML as small as possible turned out to be the best option.

Comment: I am not a fan of libs for such simple cases

Comment: there is no need to use any lib, just embed Base64-encoded font into your css directly = `cat yourfont.woff | base64`